# Loseless decomposition?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, functional-dependencies

R = GHJKL

H->L, G->K, K->L

Is D={GHJ,HK,GKL} join lossless decomposition?

I have read couple of articles on decomposition, this is what everyone suggests.

GHJKL = {HL, GHJK}

GHJK = {GK, GHJ}

I am confused after this step. What do I do next to determine whether D is lossless?

Comment: To determine if it is loseless you join the decomposed relations together. If you have the same relation prior to decomposition the decomposition was loseless(no data was lost).

Comment: @TI, can you please explain on the given example?

Comment: You have to know the candidate keys also to perform this.